# Nest multiple terms in DSL syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, dsl

I'm trying to convert following query into NEST DSL syntax:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Color"
      }
    },
    "weight": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Weight"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each of the terms is coming from the list which holds name and fieldId. So far I've managed to do this:

```
  var request2 = _client.Search<T>(s => s
               .Aggregations(aggs =>
                   aggs.Terms("Weight", x => x.Field("Weight")).Terms("Color", x => x.Field("Weight"))));
```

Which works as expected however I need to be able to supply parameters `Weight` and `Color` dynamically as the method can be called with different set of parameters. Is there a way how to use something like:

```
aggs.Terms(x => x.field( myList.foreach(y.value))));
```

I guess this would work better with the Object initializer syntax, however I would rather get this working inside dsl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var fields = new List<string>
{
    "color",
    "weight",
    "foo",
    "bar"
};

var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Aggregations(aggs =>
    {
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            aggs.Terms(field, t => t.Field(field));
        }

        return aggs;
    })
);
```

which generates the following request

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    },
    "weight": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weight"
      }
    },
    "foo": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "foo"
      }
    },
    "bar": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for, will test it tomorrow and report back. Thank you!